# Adding icons to items of Qlistview

Tags: python, pyqt, icons, pyqt5, qlistview

Straight to the issue, I want to add icons to items of `Qlistview`. I've been trying with `setData`, but it does not succeed.

**The code:**

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        iconroot = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Helvetica", 8, QtGui.QFont.Normal, italic=False)) 
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.listView = QtWidgets.QListView()
        lay.addWidget(self.listView)

        self.entry = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.listView.setModel(self.entry) 
        self.listView.setSpacing(5)

        for text in ("One", "two", "Three", "Four", 
                     "Five etc.."):
            it = QtGui.QStandardItem(text)
            self.entry.appendRow(it)
            it.setData(QtGui.QIcon(iconroot +'/images/flags'),QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Wish something like this..

[image]

Comment: what is the path of icons?

Comment: I figured out by my self, it was the path to icons.

Comment: What you point out is a Typo so your question must be closed, you should eliminate it yourself, I am going to vote to close your question and as it points is off-topic

Comment: I delete the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

#        iconroot = os.path.dirname(__file__)

        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Helvetica", 8, QtGui.QFont.Normal, italic=False)) 
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.listView = QtWidgets.QListView()
        lay.addWidget(self.listView)

        self.entry = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.listView.setModel(self.entry) 
        self.listView.setSpacing(5)

#        for text in ("One", "two", "Three", "Four", 
        for i, text in enumerate(["One", "two", "Three", "Four",                          # +++
                                  "Five etc.."]):
            it = QtGui.QStandardItem(text)
            self.entry.appendRow(it)

#            it.setData(QtGui.QIcon(iconroot +'/images/flags'), QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole)
            it.setData(QtGui.QIcon(os.path.join('images', 'bao{}.png'.format(i))),        # +++
                                   QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: I solved by myself, it was a path to icons.